# Add an "Edit Tags" link to all questions in the question lists

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits

You know that hidden control that appears in a posted question when you hover to the right of the tags and have 10k reputation?

[image]

Please put one to the right of the tags in question listings, like this:

[image]

It should require the same rep that the original edit tag link does.  This will alleviate the need for me to have to open each and every question to burn a tag.

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: [Can we have an edit tags option on the Tagged Questions interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196029/187824). Because this is moderator only request.

Comment: @hims056: I removed the moderator-tools tag.  It's not necessarily a mod-only tool, although I'll take it that way if it's the only way I can get it.

Comment: I can't say I like this much as a moderator tool. Removing tags is supposed to be a community action, not a moderator action, and we encourage users to fix everything about the question and not just the one tag. If that's the use case, give us a tag burnination tool that doesn't bump the questions. OTOH, as a 10k (or other reputation threshold) tool to quickly re-route mistagged questions to the right audience, it makes sense.

Comment: @Gilles: I don't think we're going to get the tag burnination tool; it's been floated several times already, in various forms.  Users can still open the  questions that need to be fixed.  We need to make removing bad tags easier somehow; right now, bad tags must be caught early (when they're not a problem); they become impractical to fix later when they do become a problem due to the sheer number of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure of this, the titles don't always describe the question thoroughly. While this doesn't affect mass retags, having the edit tags link always visible may encourage people to scroll through the questions page and retag whenever they notice something amiss. This may end up in a lot of bad retags.

Making it a mod-only option seems OK to me, though.